# Definition of a limit point proof

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(M, d)$ be a metric space. Let $S ⊂ M$ and $x ∈ M$. Use the
definition of limit point to prove the following.
 $x$ is a limit point of S if and only if $∀ ϵ > 0, ∃ y$ such that $y ∈ B(x,ϵ) ∩ S$ and $y ≠ x$.

So I was able to prove the forward direction, but I need help proving if $∀ ϵ > 0, ∃ y$ such that $y ∈ B(x,ϵ) ∩ S$ and $y ≠ x$, then $x$ is a limit point of S.

Definition of a limit point: x is a limit point of S provided every neighborhood of x contains elements from S distinct from x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show the following are equivalent:

1. Every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point in $S\setminus \{x\}$.
2. Every $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x$ contains a point in $S\setminus \{x\}$.

Clearly, (1) implies (2), so you need only show that (2) implies (1).

Assume (2). Let $N$ be a neighborhood of $x$. By definition of a neighborhood, there is some $\epsilon>0$ for which $B(x,\epsilon)\subset N$. Because of (2), there exists a point $y\neq x$ such that $y\in B(x,\epsilon)\cap S$. This means that $y\in N\cap S$ as well. We've now shown every neighborhood $N$ of $x$ contains a point $y\neq x$ in $S$, which proves (1).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for each $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists $y\in B(x,\epsilon)\cap S$ and $y \ne x$. Then, let $N(x)$ be a neighborhood of $x$. Since $N(x)$ is open, there is some $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon) \subset N(x)$.

Since for each $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists $y\in B(x,\epsilon)\cap S$ and $y \ne x$, it follows that $N(x)$ contains a point of $S$ other than $x$. Our choice of $N(x)$ was arbitrary, so every neighborhood of $x$ contains points $y$ of $S$ such that $y \ne x$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists y$ such that $y \in B(x, \epsilon) \cap S$ and $y \not= x$, then every neighborhood of $x$ contains an element of $S$ distinct from $x$. Hence, by definition, $x$ is a limit point of $S$.

Comment: There's more to it than that because an epsilon neighborhood is not every neighborhood.That's what our instructor told us.

Comment: I don't follow what your instructor means then. In the usual metric, $B(x, \epsilon)$ is a ball/neighborhood of radius $\epsilon$ about $x$. An open ball of radius $r$ about a point $x$ is defined as the set of all $y$ such that $d(x,y) \lt r$. That's the definition. So if $\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists y \in B(x, \epsilon)$, where $y \not= x, y \in S$, then every neighborhood/ball about $x$ contains a point of the set $S$ distinct from $x$. That makes $x$ a limit point of $S$.

Comment: I think ball is usually used for $\mathbb R^3$ and higher, and neighborhood for $\mathbb R^2$, but they are defined analogously.